# rasberrypi gui using python 2.7

Tags: gui, python-2.x

I'm trying to host run a GUI program on my pi using ssh.
but I get this error:

```
App(Tkinter.Tk(), "window name")
NameError: name 'Tkinter' is not defined.
```

however when I type "import Tkinter" in pi python, it's imported successfully. pls whats the problem and any solution?

Comment: Do you import Tkinter in the problematic script?

Comment: Why aren't you using python3?  https://pythonprogramming.net/python-3-tkinter-basics-tutorial/

Comment: i switched to python 3.5. thanks anyway.